# iOS 9.3.1 / OS X 10.11.14: Laptop doesn't show up in Airdrop locations on phone

Tags: airdrop

In the past when I was sitting near my laptop (from early 2015) with the Photos app open on my iPhone (from fall 2014), when I would tap share a picture, my laptop would show up in AirDrop.  Now it is not showing up anymore!

- From my laptop when I click on AirDrop from the Finder, my phone
  appears, and I am able to share files from my laptop to the phone.
- I have confirmed that Bluetooth and Wifi are enabled for both
  devices.
- From Settings>Bluetooth on the phone, I saw my laptop listed, but when I tried to connect, it failed.  I deleted it from the list of My Devices and tried to re-pair my laptop and computer using the Bluetooth File Exchange app on my laptop.  Even after seemingly going through the process correctly, it showed the laptop in the list of My Devices again, but as "Not Connected," and when I clicked on the info icon to see more, it said, "[Laptop name] is not supported."  But how could this be?!  I have the latest OS versions on both!
- And now when I try to send from my laptop to the phone, which was working when I started debugging this, it says that "[Phone name] does not have the necessary services."  Again -- why?!  (However, when I share through the Finder from laptop => phone, it does work, although it's the reverse direction I need to get working again.)
- I had the laptop under the setting "Allow me to be discovered by: Contact Only," but I switched it to "Everyone" -- no luck.

This is maddening.  Help!

Answer (score 0):

There are number of methods to get it working so try them out one by one what works for you.

1. Try creating new user in mac and test airdrop with 
     
   -icloud signed out
     
   -icloud signed in
2. Reset PRAM ans SMC
3. Try switching on/off bluetooth/wifi on both the devices.
4. Network reset in iPhone.
5. Test the same machines in different wifi at different location sometimes it is an issue of wifi router also. // This has happened with me.
6. Check firewall in mac and disable it temporarily.
7. Try without connecting to any network on both the devices i.e. forget wifi on both devices but enable wifi/bluetooth on both.
8. Try it in Safe mode.
9. If you have another mac available then try to airdrop with mac to mac.

Happy airdrop debugging :P